# The page isn't working - myproject.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

My project (laravel 5.5 using php 7.0.0)works fine on my localhost. My server uses a global php version of 5.6. I have created a sub-domain (`public_html/myproject`) for my project. 
But the php version for my sub-domain, i have upgraded it to php 7. When i run `myproject.domain.com` i get the error

> This page isn’t working
>   myproject.domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

I have tried a lot solutions online but none of them seems to work for me. What could i be missing out?

Comment: Turn on development mode and give us the actual error.

Comment: how do i turn on development mode @tyteen4a03. i have this already in my env  `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: In your `.env` file `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: @Troyer, i already have that

Comment: Does your document root point to `/public`?

Comment: @Konafets i don't get you right

Comment: Laravels entry point is `public/index.php`, The document_root of apache/nginx (depending on your hoster) must point to `public_html/myproject/public`. 

BTW: `public_html/myproject/` is not a sub-domain, but a subfolder. A subdomain is something like `www`, `stats`, `blog`.

However. your domain record must point to `public_html/myproject/public`.

Comment: @Konafets, yes i am sure it points to the /public. is there any error log that can tell where the problem is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your index.php file for the first require statement and make sure that the autoload file is located correctly `require_once '../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';` was the right address in my case. My laravel folder was just above my html folder so it worked like this.